# MVC3 TextBoxFor adding a class removes the input-validation-error validation css class

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a textboxfor control on my razor view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrimaryAddressLine1)
```

If the user leaves this field blank the validation will add class="input-validation-error" to the field changing its color to red (as expected). However if i try to add a custom css class to the field like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrimaryAddressLine1, new { @Class = "addressfield" })
```

I loose the red color as the "input-validation-error" class is no longer added to the control.

How can i keep the red color and add my custom css class?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but typically @class would be lowercased.

Comment: how about adding color=red in the addressfield class to be sure?  :)

Comment: are you trying to implement the conditional validation over there?

Comment: How are you adding the validation message? are you using @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryAddressLine1). And this is happening because you a using your own class so if you want to keep the color just add background-color:red to your addressfield class or remove your addressfield class and just add  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrimaryAddressLine1, new { style = "any styles you want" }) this will not override the input-validation-error class

Comment: Moises: I dont want to use a style attribute as i have several fields all with the same style and i would expect to style them all with a css class.  I dont want to add a validation message next to each field as it wont work with my design i use a validation summary at the top of the page.   gardarvalur: if i just add color=red the field will always be red! i only want red when there is a validation error. Erik: it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the ValidationMessageFor option is suitable in most cases i don't actually want a message next to the field. I use a ValidationSummary at the top of the page to list the errors. Adding a style attribute is also acceptable however i have several fields and i want to set the style on all of them to match and css would be the way i would expect to achieve this.

I've created a custom textboxfor which allows me to specify if the field is "locked" or "unlocked" I've made a few changes to make it add the validation class if there is a fault with the field while keeping any custom css classes.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString LockableTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool locked)
    {
        string fullName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

        // Convert htmlAttributes into a dictionary
        RouteValueDictionary dic = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        // Get the validation attributes
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);            
        IDictionary<string, object> validationAttributes = helper
            .GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), metadata);

        // Merge attributes
        foreach (var item in validationAttributes)
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey(Key))
                dic[Key] = string.Format("{0} {1}", dic[Key], Value);
            else
                dic.Add(Key, Value);
        }            

        // If there are any errors for a named field, we add the CSS attribute.
        ModelState modelState;
        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out modelState) && modelState.Errors.Count > 0)
            dic.HikiAddUpdateItem("class", HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName);

        // Toggle readonly
        if (locked)
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey("readonly"))
                dic["readonly"] = "readonly"
            else
                dic.Add("readonly", "readonly");                
        }

        // Return textbox
        return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, dic);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the @Class to @class.  That did the trick for me.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrimaryAddressLine1, new { @class = "addressfield" })
```

Comment: Nice find.  For some reason I seem to always use uppercase Class and never realized it made a difference until now.  Lower case class worked great for this, thanks.

Comment: Remember to mark it as the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: I wish I could, I wasn't the original poster unfortunately.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

add validatorfor below the textbox line like below

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CompanyName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(c=>c.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CompanyName, "", new { @style="color:blue;"})
            </div>
        </div>
```

and output will like this

[image]

Comment: I don't want to add validation messages next to each field as it wont work with the design of my application.  I want the field to have a given style but if there is a validation error change the field to red.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model  => model.PrimaryAddressLine1, new { @id = "oid", @class= "addressfield" })
<span style="color: Red">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model  => model.PrimaryAddressLine1)</span>
```

Comment: This just adds the validation message next to the field it wont't change the css class of the actual field. I don't want to add validation messages next to each field as it wont work in my design.